# QFutureIterator::next segfaults

Tags: qt, qt4, qtconcurrent

I have the following Qt code, which segfaults in `next()`.
I looked into the `QtConcurrent` code and it is not obvious to me, why it fails.

```
namespace {
    std::tuple<QString, std::exception_ptr> test( const int& data ) {
        return std::make_tuple( QString(), std::exception_ptr() );
    }
}

void
start() {
    QVector<int> downloadList;
    downloadList.push_back( 1 );
    downloadList.push_back( 2 );

    auto future = QtConcurrent::mapped( downloadList, test );

    QFutureIterator<std::tuple<QString, std::exception_ptr>> it( future );
    while( it.hasNext() ) {
        auto& tuple = it.next();
    }
}
```

The point it fails is:

```
const T *pointer() const
{
    if (mapIterator.value().isVector())
->      return &(reinterpret_cast<const QVector<T> *>(mapIterator.value().result)->at(m_vectorIndex));
    else
        return reinterpret_cast<const T *>(mapIterator.value().result);
}
```

---

**Update:**

The same crash for `QFuture::const_iterator`.

---

**Note:**

If I can believe *GDB*, `this` in `QVector::at`  is `0x0`. Then I assume that `mapIterator.value().result` already is a `nullptr`, why, I have no idea.

Comment: Just asking... are you sure you can use an iterator on a QFuture before the QFuture has finished?

Comment: According to the [doc](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qfutureiterator.html#details), yes.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the *Qt4* docs are wrong, yet again (anyone surprised?). At least I could not find a reference to a `waitForResult( int )` call in the iterators.

What does work though is using `resultAt` directly.

So you would replace

```
for( auto it = future.begin(); it != future.end(); ++it ) {
    auto& result = *it;
```

with

```
for( int i = 0; i != count; ++i ) {
    auto result = future.resultAt( i );
```

to prevent it from crashing.

Comment: And I do hope they base their `QFuture` on `std::future` in _Qt6_.